# AngularJS - Fetch list of files and extract file name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Directory Structure for locale files**

```
app/common/locale/language-FR.json
app/common/locale/language-EN.json
```

The files are part of code base and do not reside on server side. Used below code to read file names and extension but no luck. The path ro r

```
    var myloc = '/common/locale/language-';
    var locarray = myloc.split("-");
    delete locarray[(locarray.length-1)];
    var arraytext = locarray.join("/");
```

How could I achieve below

1. Fetch list of files from the specified folder path (**language-FR.json**)
2. Extract file name (ex: **FR, EN**)
3. Make array of the file names

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that wiht angularjs, since AngularJS is client side(runs in browser).

One thing you could do is to write a backend api to do the same. you can achieve with nodejs.

Comment: As I said, the codebase is in same folder and the files do not reside on server. For ex: ` var nameString = "/common/locale/language-EN.json";
        var filename = nameString.split("/").pop();`

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the files and have the file paths in an array, you could do as such:

```js
var arr = ["app/common/locale/language-FR.json","app/common/locale/language-EN.json"];

var langStr = "";
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  var locarray = arr[i].split("-");
  var langarray = locarray[1].split(".");
  langStr += langarray[0] + "/";
}
console.log(langStr);
```

Comment: To have file paths in array, we first need to have list of files. $.getScript("common/locale/")